# List of Lists in Type Declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have been at this code for almost 2 hours, and I keep getting the same compiler error message. I have done my research but just cannot find an answer

```
buildTable :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]

buildTable n m fun = [[ fun x y 
                    | x <- [0..n-1]]
                    | y <- [0..m-1]]


lookupAns :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> Int
lookupAns len1 len2 theArray = 
    theArray !! len1 !! len2


lcsLength :: String -> String -> Int
lcsLength s1 s2 = 
  let 
    n1 = (length s1)
    n2 = (length s2)
    table = buildTable (n1 n2 lcsHelp)

    lcsHelp = if ( n1 == 0 || n2 == 0 )
                then 0

                else if ( last s1 == last s2 )

                then                    
                    (lookupAns
                        (n1 - 1)
                        n2
                        table)
                        + 1
                else
                    max 
                        (lookupAns 
                            n1
                            (n2-1)
                            table)
                        (lookupAns
                            (n1-1)
                            n2
                            table)





    in lookupAns
        (length s1)
        (length s2)
        table
```

Now I get the same error message no matter what I try. The error message is " Couldn't match expected type '[[Int]] -> Int' with actual type [Int]" With other specifications pointing to the first call of max towards the end of the code. Please help, this is really frustrating

It now compiles and runs with my new code. I'll be sure to post it later as it is getting kinda late, and I'm gonna put this down for the night.

Comment: Note that lists aren't very good for this type of thing, since they have large overhead in terms of space, and slow _O(n)_ indexing. They're OK for small cases or prototyping, but for anything serious you should probably look into using arrays or vectors instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
table = buildTable (n1 n2 lcsHelp)
```

`buildTable` has type `Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]`. `buildTable (n1 n2 lcsHelp)` is applying it to one argument, namely `(n1 n2 lcsHelp)`. So `table` would have type `Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]`, which is invalid to pass as the third argument to `lookupAns`.

Nevermind that `(n1 n2 lcsHelp)` is trying to apply an integer `n1` to two things, which is obvious garbage.

I don't get the error message you quote, though. GHCi gives me:

```
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( bar.hs, interpreted )

bar.hs:18:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `[[Int]]'
                with actual type `Int -> (Int -> Int -> a0) -> [[a0]]'
    In the return type of a call of `buildTable'
    In the expression: buildTable (n1 n2 lcsHelp)
    In an equation for `table': table = buildTable (n1 n2 lcsHelp)
```

I'm not sure whether that's because the code you've posted isn't actually the code you compiled to get your error message (which is hinted at by the fact that you had to correct a typo), or just that GHCi is picking up the inconsistency at a different point than the compiler you're using.

I'm guessing you probably meant:

```
table = buildTable n1 n2 lcsHelp
```

But that gives me a different error again.

Answer (score 1):

The first lookupAns in lcslength is applied to too few arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted the code on [hpaste](http://hpaste.org/66851) so that it is easier to find out the issue. As @Ben already pointed out, the issue is the  type of the `table`.

`buildTable` function has the type `Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]`. You are calling it as `table = buildTable (n1 n2 lcsHelp)`. So, the type of `table` will be `Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]`. This type is invalid to pass to the `lookupAns` function which has the type `Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> Int`

And if you were to do something like this `table = buildTable n1 n2 lcsHelp` which I believe might be your intent, then the type signature for `buildTable` has to change, as you will encounter this error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int -> Int -> Int'
            with actual type `Int'
In the third argument of `buildTable', namely `lcsHelp'
```

And this happens because now the `lcsHelp` function, which returns an `Int` (because of the return value from the `if..else` statements) doesn't match the actual type of the `buildTable` function.

So, if you can explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve, it will be easier to help you out. Most likely the `lcsHelp` function's type is what you need to revisit. May be the `buildTable` function needn't take a function as the input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

couple of comments
1. `lcsHelp` takes no args
2. `lookupAns` in **else-if-then** takes wrong arguments, missing `table`

I have a little modified to: http://hpaste.org/66862